# masked the password input to UITextfield

Tags: iphone

I hope to mask the text input to `UITextField` as:

```
"ABCDE" to
"*****"
```

below are my codes without function

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   int l=[textField.text length];
   range=NSMakeRange(1, l );
   string=[[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"*"] autorelease];
   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITextField` supports password input itself, just set its `secureTextEntry` property to `YES`. (see `UITextInputTraits` protocol docs for more details)